# Appengine looping across large datasets

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I need to loop over a large dataset within appengine. Ofcourse, as the datastore times out after a small amount of time, I decided to use tasks to solve this problem, here's an attempt to explain the method I'm trying to use:

```
Initialization of task via http post
0) Create query (entity.query()), and set a batch_size limit (i.e. 500)
1) Check if there are any cursors--if this is the first time running, there won't be any.
2a) If there are no cursors, use iter() with the following options: produce_cursors = true, limit= batch_size
2b) If there are curors, use iter() with same options as 2a + set start_cursor to the cursor.
3) Do a for loop to iterate through the results pulled by iter()
4) Get cursor_after()
5) Queue new task (basically re-run the task that was running) passing the cursor into the payload.
```

So if this code were to work the way I wanted, there'd only be 1 task running at any particular time in the queue. However, I started running the task this morning and 3 hours later when I looked at the queue, there were 4 tasks in it! This is weird because the new task should only be launched at the end of the task launching it.

Here's the actual code with no edits:

```
class send_missed_swipes(BaseHandler): #disabled
    def post(self):
        """Loops across entire database (as filtered) """
        #Settings
        BATCH_SIZE = 500
        cursor = self.request.get('cursor')
        start = datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        end = datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 5, 0, 0, 00, 0)

        #Filters
        swipes = responses.query()
        swipes = swipes.filter(responses.date>start)

        if cursor:
            num_updated = int(self.request.get('num_updated'))
            cursor = ndb.Cursor.from_websafe_string(cursor)
            swipes = swipes.iter(produce_cursors=True,limit=BATCH_SIZE,start_cursor=cursor)
        else:
            num_updated = 0
            swipes = swipes.iter(produce_cursors=True,limit=BATCH_SIZE)

        count = 0
        for swipe in swipes:
            count += 1

            if swipe.date>end:
                pass
            else:
                uKey = str(swipe.uuId.urlsafe())
                pKey = str(swipe.pId.urlsafe())
                act = swipe.act
                taskqueue.add(queue_name="analyzeData", url="/admin/analyzeData/send_swipes", params={'act':act,'uKey':uKey,'pKey':pKey})
                num_updated += 1

        logging.info('count = '+str(count))
        logging.info('num updated = '+str(num_updated))
        cursor = swipes.cursor_after().to_websafe_string()
        taskqueue.add(queue_name="default", url="/admin/analyzeData/send_missed_swipes", params={'cursor':cursor,'num_updated':num_updated})
```

This is a bit of a complicated question, so please let me know if I need to explain it better. And thanks for the help!

p.s. Threadsafe is false in app.yaml

Comment: "I decided to use tasks to solve this problem, now I have two problems." ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe a task can be executed multiple times, therefore it is important to make your process idempotent.

From doc https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push

> Note that this example is not idempotent. It is possible for the task
>   queue to execute a task more than once. In this case, the counter is
>   incremented each time the task is run, possibly skewing the results.

You can create task with name to handle this
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/#Python_Task_names

I'm curious why threadsafe=False in your yaml?

Comment: If I were struggling with multiple executions of a task that I wanted to run only once, I would certainly try threadsafe=False as well in case it might help.  In this case it does not help however.

Comment: I don't think that will help, since task can always be executed more than once regardless your threadsafe setting

Comment: Thanks @maracadian, tried this out and it worked perfectly! Some quick things I learned in the process: 

- Task names are unique over a period of approximately 7 days. This is relevant because after the test run, I decided it was good enough to start working. So I purged my queue and re-ran the script but got a 'tombstoned' task error. I had to add a prefix in the name to solve this problem to make the name unique.

- Also I realized that perhaps backends would've been a better use-case for this, but since I had most of my code written already, I'm glad I could just run it and be done!

Answer (score 1):

A bit off topic (since I'm not addressing your problems), but this sounds like a job for [map reduce](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/dataprocessing/).

On topic: you can create custom queue with `max_concurrent_requests=1`. You could still have multiple tasks in the queue, but only one would be executing at a time.